# CMAKE_BUILD_DIR pointing to symlink and causing issues

Tags: cmake

in my build system i have `/private/tmp/ws` and there is symlink `/tmp` to this.
I call a script which takes argument CMAKE_BUILD_DIR , but taking `/tmp/ws/...`, rather `/private/tmp/ws/..`

example error

```
File "/private/tmp/ws/tools_path/create_symbol_list.py", line 212, in <module>
  main()
File "/private/tmp/ws/tools_path/create_symbol_list.py", line 188, in main
  obj_file_path = find_object_file(build_folder_path=user_args.path_to_build_folder,
File "/private/tmp/ws/tools_path/create_symbol_list.py", line 83, in find_object_file
  raise Exception("Compiled object for source file: {} was not found at expected path: {}"
Exception: Compiled object for source file: /private/tmp/ws/src_path/overlay_id_db.c was not found at expected path: /tmp/ws/modem/output_path/CMakeFiles/libname1.dir//private/tmp/ws/src_path/overlay_id_db.c.obj
```

Missing file `/tmp/ws/modem/output_path/CMakeFiles/libname1.dir/`/private/tmp/`ws/src_path/overlay_id_db.c.obj` 
is present at `/tmp/ws/modem/output_path/CMakeFiles/libname1.dir`/tmp`/ws/src_path/overlay_id_db.c.obj` which means CMAKE_BUILD_DIR is taking symlink.

anyway to fix this?

Comment: "causing issues" - Please, elaborate these issues. Otherwise it is unclear what is your problem.

Comment: sorry for that, updated now, please see if you can help.

Comment: `CMAKE_BUILD_DIR` is not a documented cmake variable, at least according to a quick search. Also shouldn't you be fixing the python script, if it cannot deal with symlinks in a path?

Comment: Script is just taking correct, .obj file itself in wrong place.